# Most common regex on Django URLs

Tags: regex, django

I usually struggle with Regex in general, I wonder if there is something like a glossary of common regex to provide to URLS.py on django.
It would be really helpful to have some sort of cheatsheet of urls.py regex formation.

Any experience Django user can maybe list their most common urls.py regex inputs?

Answer (score 2):

There is not a "common" list that I use, but there are are a few common patterns, as well as some simple rules:

1. The caret character (^) means "starts with".
2. The dollar sign ($) means "ends".
3. Question mark (?) means "optional".
4. You can group and named a pattern using the (?Ppattern) format.

So, for simple URLs, without any parameters, you'll want to to learn the `^url$` pattern. Examples:

```
url(r'^foo$', 'app.view')
url(r'^foo/subdirectory/?$', 'app.view')
```

For parameters, you'll want to use the grouping mechanism:

```
url(r'^foo/(?P<parameter_name>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.view')
url(r'^foo/(?P<parameter_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<parameter_two_name>[-\w]+)/$', 'app.view')
```

The `[-\w]` pattern means "Anything that isn't whitespace". The brackets `[]` establish that you'll accept a character in a range of possible characters as a match, the `\w` is a short cut for "whitespace character", and the `-` in front of the short cut means "anything not". The "+" after the brackets means "the pattern before must repeat".

RegEx's are a full and complex topic on their own, but the above three examples cover about 90% of what's in most of my `urls.py` files.